# How to store aditional data in laravel JOB table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

Scenario: A user can do multiple assignments In a class.

So user has an ID [user_id], assignment has an ID [assignment_id], user may do the assignment in multiple time. therefore an assignment that user did has an attempt number [assignment_attempt ].

I use Laravel database queue to store assignment related data in database.

Now I want to delete all the records related to an assignment that user did in given attempt.

I don't want to store the job id in another table because It increase number of database request per second in may server.

Is there a way to store the user_id, assignment_id, assignment_attempt on the JOB table?

Comment: I would not touch the job table, it will also be empty when the queue has done its work

Comment: Your job class can take parameters and is serialised in the jobs table. Isn't that enough?